# Spring Boot 3 WebFlux lacks http metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-micrometer

I've got a `Spring Boot 3 WebFlux` application which has actuator on the classpath with enabled metrics. However, going to `/actuator/prometheus` I can't see the `http.metrics`. I realize that there were some changes, however those metrics should be out of the box from my understanding, espescially that I can see other kind of metrics such as `jvm`, `logging` etc.

Since we use hexagonal architecture in the project our adapter for web has the following dependencies:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui")

implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
```

All of these are in version `3.0.4`